# Continuous copy or replication from MongoDB Atlas to Google BigQuery

Tags: mongodb, google-bigquery, replication

We have IoT data coming into MongoDB Atlas and will need to continuously copy/replicate it into Google BigQuery. Trying to find a way that does not involve 3rd party SAAS solution due to budget constraints. We'll need to copy the whole inserted documents and store them in BigQuery as the raw data. If anyone has done this before, kindly share what you have used or done.

I have looked into this article ["A data pipeline for MongoDB Atlas and BigQuery using Dataflow"](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/mongodb-atlas-and-bigquery-dataflow-templates) from Google and have implemented: the section "#1.MongoDB to BigQuery template" but it copies all existing data then completes the job; as well as the section "#3. MongoDB to BigQuery CDC template" but this doesn't seem to capture any of the incoming data.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @LearnItDom, Have you tried using the **\`Mongoexpert\`** , as mentioned in the *Method : 2* of this [document](https://hevodata.com/blog/mongodb-to-bigquery/#:~:text=Step%201%3A%20Extract%20Data%20from%20MongoDB,-This%20is%20the&text=The%20utility%20can%20be%20used,not%20from%20the%20Mongo%20Shell.) ? This might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Diraj. I am looking for a more real time process so I am exploring using code now to watch mongodb’s change stream. Will update what I end up using once done.

Comment: @DhirajSingh have you found a solution or a direction how to implement this? Thank you

Answer (score -2):

You can try using the **[Mongoexpert](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoexport/)** as mentioned in Method : 2 of this [document](https://hevodata.com/blog/mongodb-to-bigquery/#:%7E:text=Step%201%3A%20Extract%20Data%20from%20MongoDB,-This%20is%20the&text=The%20utility%20can%20be%20used,not%20from%20the%20Mongo%20Shell.).

Using the `Mongoexpert`, you can produce a **JSON** or **CSV** export of data stored in a MongoDB instance. You can follow the detailed steps in this [documentation](https://hevodata.com/blog/mongodb-to-bigquery/#:%7E:text=Step%201%3A%20Extract%20Data%20from%20MongoDB,-This%20is%20the&text=The%20utility%20can%20be%20used,not%20from%20the%20Mongo%20Shell.).